# How to match OpenJFX GA release versions with github tag versions?

Tags: java, javafx, openjfx, java-13

I'm trying to figure out how to match the versions of OpenJFX general availability releases like 13.0.2 with any tags available in https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/releases. The numbering format of those tags is always something like X+Y. Then how can I know OpenJFX 13, 13.0.1 and 13.0.2 match with which tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Repositories**

OpenJFX has been developed in the HG Mercurial repository [`openjfx/jfx-dev/rt`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/jfx-dev/rt/), up until it was made read only and migrated to the new official GitHub [openjdk/jfx](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx) repository (see [Proposal: Migrate official jfx repo to GitHub + Skara tooling](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2019-September/023526.html)). This happened at the end of September 2019, right after the release of JavaFX 13.

Whenever there was a major release, the OpenJFX repo was branched (under HG):

- JavaFX 11: [openjfx/11-dev/rt](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/11-dev/rt/)
- JavaFX 12: [openjfx/12-dev/rt](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/12-dev/rt/)
- JavaFX 13: [openjfx/13-dev/rt](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/13-dev/rt/)

and the development continued in the master branch `openjfx/jfx-dev/rt`, which is now at https://github.com/openjdk/jfx

Note that the repository https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx was a temporary *mirror* of HG. As you can read now:

> This repository is an obsolete GIT mirror of the formerly-official HG repo on OpenJDK.

JavaFX 14 hasn't been released yet, but as mentioned, all the development is happening now at GitHub (there are a few commits in HG of the last days of September though).

**Early access**

All the tags that you see before a release are early access snapshots, like 14-ea+1,..., [14-ea+7](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/releases/tag/14%2B7), or even [15-ea+1](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/releases/tag/15%2B1).

Of course, you can still find the old early access tags for released versions, like [13-ea+14](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/releases/tag/13%2B14).

**Minor releases**

Since the releases (11, 12, 13) are at HG, the tags related to new minor releases, like 13.0.1, can be found there:

- [13.0.1](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/13-dev/rt/rev/4ace6d5d8502)
- [13.0.2](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/13-dev/rt/rev/a2baea82efbc)

**Maven artifacts**

For every tag (early access and minor release) there are published artifacts to [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx).

[image: Maven Central]

**LTS**

Note that regarding JavaFX 11, you won't find the maven artifacts for the releases since 11.0.3, as these are LTS. You can find them [here](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/).

Comment: I see. So there aren't any tags related to OpenJFX 13 minor releases in the github repo, they're only in the HG repo?

Comment: Exactly, we have to wait until JavaFX 14 major/minor releases